# How to analyze a dB graph?

Tags: audio, sound

The following chart represents almost 5 hours of input received by a sonometer (BENETECH GM1356) at each second in an apartment room.

[image]

How can I find the answers to the following questions from this chart:

1. How many minutes in total are above 60 dB?
2. What level of dB is the most dominant?
3. What is the level of background[/underlying noise](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/noise-nuisances-how-councils-deal-with-complaints) and what is the level of actual sound?

But, most importantly: **How can I convert dB to dBA?**

Comment: Since this is probably a homework assignment, explain how far you got and what you don't understand.

Comment: @user1850479, he he he! This is not a homework assignment. I am trying to sue my neighbor. And, that is why I need to analyze this data to show evidence of their noise making habit.

Comment: @jsotola, 0-2000 is **probably** the background noise. Coz, they were not making noise at that time. check this link https://www.gov.uk/guidance/noise-nuisances-how-councils-deal-with-complaints

Comment: @jsotola, most dominant means, (**around**) which dB is present most of the time.

Comment: @jsotola, what I am not understanding is the sudden drop of dB from 2000 to around 3000. The same kind of drop is visible around 16000.

Comment: @jsotola, except the bars seem to be every second rather than every minute.

Comment: @jsotola, *background noise* means **underlying noise** in this guideline: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/noise-nuisances-how-councils-deal-with-complaints

Comment: _ "How can I find the answers to the following questions from this chart"_ - You can't. Use the raw data, then getting the answers you want will be trivial.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, hmm... I also have an excel sheet...

Comment: @jsotola, ok, understood. Thanks!!! :D

Comment: you have some drops at 8000

Comment: @jsotola, hmm... probably some people left the room at that time, and later joined again.

Comment: You can't convert dB to dBA. You have to set the meter to dBA when you make the measurements. It should be already in dBA or dBC - but you should have either set it or noted what the meter was using when you made the measurements.

Answer (score 1):

> How many minutes in total are above 60 dB?

You can't tell that from the graph alone.

Loudness can change many times in a second, and one of the pixels in your image is 24 seconds long – and you're not specifying whether "minute above 60 dB" means that a single instant in that minute was above 60 dB, or the average loudness in that minute, or somethingelse.

> What level of dB is the most dominant?

"Dominant" is not defined. Is it "average", is it "median", is it "most frequent value"? All three will give different answers. None of the answers will be relevant at all, again, because of the insufficient sampling.

> What is the level of background/underlying noise and what is the level of actual sound?

Impossible to say without a noise and signal model. What's "actual sound" and how does that distinction even matter to regulations?

Generally, hard to tell from a power measurement: You'd have to make assumptions about noise being constant or changing slowly, and I don't see that being true in reality.

> How can I convert dB to dBA?

not at all, per se. dB says nothing about what it was measured to, relatively. Especially, it doesn't say that whatever the volume measurement was based on did A-weighting. So, you only get dB relative to whatever the instrument was considering 0 dB. That being a measurement device, it'll certainly be calibrated, but you'll need to read the manual. Also, the wikipedia article on "decibel" and "dBA", in that order.